# Ansible - Check if multiple directories exist - if so run a script on each directory - How?

Tags: ansible

Im creating a deployment playbook for our web services.  Each web service is in its own directory such as:

```
/webapps/service-one/
/webapps/service-two/
/webapps/service-three/
```

I want to check to see if the service directory exists, and if so, I want to run a shell script that stops the service gracefully. Currently, I am able to complete this step by using `ignore_errors: yes`.

```
- name: Stop services
  with_items: services_to_stop
  shell: "/webapps/scripts/stopService.sh {{item}}"
  ignore_errors: yes
```

While this works, the output is very messy if one of the directories doesnt exist or a service is being deployed for the first time.  I effectively want to something like one of these:

This:

```
- name: Stop services
  with_items: services_to_stop
  shell: "/webapps/scripts/stopService.sh {{item}}"
  when: shell: [ -d /webapps/{{item}} ]
```

or this:

```
- name: Stop services
  with_items: services_to_stop
  shell: "/webapps/scripts/stopService.sh {{item}}"
  stat: 
    path: /webapps/{{item}}
  register: path
  when: path.stat.exists == True
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd collect facts first and then do only necessary things.

```
 - name: Check existing services
   stat:
     path: "/tmp/{{ item }}"
   with_items: "{{ services_to_stop }}"
   register: services_stat

 - name: Stop existing services
   with_items: "{{ services_stat.results | selectattr('stat.exists') | map(attribute='item') | list }}"
   shell: "/webapps/scripts/stopService.sh {{ item }}"
```

Also note, that bare variables in `with_items` don't work since Ansible 2.2, so you should template them.

Comment: nice use of jinja filtering, particularly the map() and list filters in sequence, that's an approach I hadn't seen before.

Comment: This is pretty bang on what I am looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This will let you get a list of existing directory names into the list variable `dir_names` (use `recurse: no` to read only the first level under webapps):

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    dir_names: []

  tasks:
    - find:
        paths: "/webapps"
        file_type: directory
        recurse: no
      register: tmp_dirs
    - set_fact:  dir_names="{{ dir_names+ [item['path']] }}"
      no_log: True
      with_items:
        - "{{ tmp_dirs['files'] }}"

    - debug: var=dir_names
```

You can then use `dir_names` in your "Stop services" task via a with_items. It looks like you're intending to use only the name of the directory under "webapps" so you probably want to use the `| basename` jinja2 filter to get that, so something like this:

```
- name: Stop services
  with_items: "{{ dir_names }}"
  shell: "/webapps/scripts/stopService.sh {{item | basename }}"
```

Comment: using @Konstantin's jinja filters example, you could skip the set_fact in my answer and just use `"{{ tmp_dirs['files'] | map(attribute='path') | list }}"` in the stop services task